# Python - string of binary escape sequences as literal

Tags: python, string

I need to print out a string of binary escape sequences, e.g. `\x05\x03\x87`, exactly as they appear. When I try to print them, Python returns a string of weird non-ASCII characters. How can I print them as a string literal?

Comment: Please show some code.  You seem to confuse the actual contents of a string with its representation in Python code, and we can only tell you what's the problem is if you show us the code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`repr`

```
>>> a='\x05\x03\x87'
>>> print a
?
>>> print repr(a)
'\x05\x03\x87'
```

**EDIT**

Sven makes the point that the OP might want *every* character dumped in hex, even the printable ones, in which case, the best solution I can think of is:

```
>>> print ''.join(map(lambda c:'\\x%02x'%c, map(ord, a)))
\x05\x03\x87
```

**ADDITIONAL EDIT**

Four years later, it occurs to me that this might be both faster and more readable:

```
>>> print ''.join(map(lambda c:'\\x%02x'% ord(c), a))
```

or even

```
>>> print ''.join([ '\\x%02x'% ord(c) for c in a ])
```

Comment: `' '` -- do you think that *isn't* what the OP wants?

Comment: At least from the wording of the question, he would want to print `'\x20'` exactly as it appears.  I guess the problem is some confusion regarding string escaping, and I don't think the current answers resolve this confusion in any way.  This answer has the additional problem that the representation of a string is implementation-defined, so you can't rely on this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [string-escape encoding](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings):

```
>>> print '\x05\x03\x87'.encode('string-escape')
\x05\x03\x87
```

From docs:

> Produce a string that is suitable as string literal in Python source code

This will essentially give you the same thing as `repr()`, without those pesky quotes.

Note that like Malvolio's answer, this assumes that you only want the escaped version for non-printable characters, if this is not what you want please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You can derive your own subclass of `str` that behaves & prints the way you desire, yet can be used almost anywhere a regular string could be and has all the same built-in methods.

As you can see, the example prints the hex values of *all* the characters it contains, whether they're printable normally or not -- something which could be done differently if you wanted, of course.

```
class HexStr(str):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "'" + ''.join('\\x{:02x}'.format(ord(ch)) for ch in self) + "'"
    __str__ = __repr__

a = HexStr('abc\x05\x03\x87')
print a
print str(a)
print repr(a)
```

Output:

```
'\x61\x62\x63\x05\x03\x87'
'\x61\x62\x63\x05\x03\x87'
'\x61\x62\x63\x05\x03\x87'
```