# bytes array format for mac address

Tags: python, arrays, format

Trying to convert `MAC` into `bytearray` format.

Tried to convert into `utf-8` but didn't get the output as expected.

```
values=("002A2C2D123A")
update_mac1=bytearray.fromhex(values)
```

It does not like byte number 5 which is 12 this is what my output looks like

```
bytearray(b'\x00*,-\x12:')
```

i'm looking for something like:

```
(b'\x00\x2A\x2C\x2D\x12\x3A
```

Comment: Have a look at this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649407/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-python

Answer (score 0):

That's a matter of string formatting. You got the value you expected, but it doesn't print how you expected it to.

```
>>> print(b'\x00\x2A\x2C\x2D\x12\x3A')
b'\x00*,-\x12:'
```

If you want to *print* the string you mentioned, you can format each character in the sequence.

```
>>> print(''.join(f'\\x{c:02x}' for c in b'\x00\x2A\x2C\x2D\x12\x3A'))
\x00\x2a\x2c\x2d\x12\x3a
```

(That is a Python 3.6 version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261109/python-string-of-binary-escape-sequences-as-literal).)

But be aware that the string printed out actually includes `\x`, and isn't a byte array.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your code correctly converts any hexadecimal string into a `bytearray`, but it sounds like you might be looking for something else.