# How do I append a list in python using a for loop and replace function?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, replace

I web scraped some stock tickers off a website and the text inside the span tags has `'\xa0AYTU\xa0'` as an example. I'm trying to remove `'\xa0'` from either side of the ticker using `replace('xa0','')`. However, when I go to append the list after I replaced the characters it appends the list with `'\xa0AYTU\xa0'` no matter what..

Here is my for loop in question.

```
fu_tickers = []

for t in match_fu.find_all('span'):
    temp = str(t.text)
    temp2 = temp.replace('xa0','')
    fu_tickers.append(temp2)

print(fu_tickers)
```

When I insert `print(temp2)` inside the for loop I can see it properly removes the characters but for some reason will not append `temp2` string to the `fu_tickers` list with the characters removed.

Current results = `['\xa0AYTU\xa0', '\xa0CETX\xa0', '\xa0CHFS\xa0']`

Desired results = `['AYTU', 'CETX', 'CHFS']`

Comment: That's an escape sequence, those characters aren't actually in the string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - string of binary escape sequences as literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261109/python-string-of-binary-escape-sequences-as-literal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\` to `'xa0'` in `str.replace`:

```
lst = ['\xa0AYTU\xa0', '\xa0CETX\xa0', '\xa0CHFS\xa0']
lst = [i.replace('\xa0', '') for i in lst]

print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
['AYTU', 'CETX', 'CHFS']
```

---

Or use `str.strip`:

```
lst = ['\xa0AYTU\xa0', '\xa0CETX\xa0', '\xa0CHFS\xa0']
lst = [i.strip() for i in lst]

print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
['AYTU', 'CETX', 'CHFS']
```

Comment: omg im an idiot, didn't even realize i was missing the \....What kind of for loop is that where you can place variables before the for? Looks alot cleaner, didn't know you could do that

Comment: Probably worth explains escape sequences

Comment: @prime90 that's a list comprehension, not a for loop. It's a special construct for creating lists using mapping/filtering operations. Set and dict comprehensions also exist, and generator expressions that create generators that all work similarly

Comment: @prime90 That's called _list comprehension_. You can read about them [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) for example. Super useful.